# Send mail using php with or without attachment

Tags: php

I'm using php code that have option for attachment in mail, everything works great when i have attachment, but when i don't have it mail doesn't go to recipient. also i have a problem with echo message when mail is sent, i don't receive any message.  here is code I use :)

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

$to="mares.p@hotmail.com";
$subject="Online Prijava";
$from = stripslashes($_POST['ime'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email_adresa']).">";

if(empty($_POST['ime'])  || empty($_POST['email_adresa']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Greska: nisu uneta sva obavezna polja";
}

$mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

$tmp_name = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['type'];
$file_name = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['size'];

$message = "PODACI U PSU:
\n\n Razred: " .$_POST['razred']. "
\n\n Boja: " .$_POST['boja']. "
\n\n Tip dlake: " .$_POST['tip_dlake']. "
\n\n Velicina: " .$_POST['velicina']. "
\n\n Pol: " .$_POST['pol']. "
\n\n Visina: " .$_POST['visina']. "
\n\n Tezina: " .$_POST['tezina']. "
\n\n Ime psa: " .$_POST['ime_psa']. "
\n\n Broj pedigra: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea']. "
\n\n Datum rodjenja: " .$_POST['datum_rodjenja']. "
\n\n Otac: " .$_POST['otac']. "
\n\n Broj pedigrea oca: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea_oca']. "
\n\n Majka: " .$_POST['majka']. "
\n\n Broj pedigra majke: " .$_POST['broj_pedigra_majke']. "
\n\n Odgajivac: " .$_POST['odgajivac']. "
\n\n
\n\nPODACI O VLASNIKU
\n\n Ime: " .$_POST['ime']. "
\n\n Adresa: " .$_POST['adresa']. "
\n\n Grad: " .$_POST['grad']. "
\n\n Drzava: " .$_POST['drzava']. "
\n\n Telefon: " .$_POST['telefon']. "
\n\n Email adresa: " .$_POST['email_adresa'];

if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
  if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){
     $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
     $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
     fclose($file);
     $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
 }

  $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
     "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
     " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
     $message . "\n\n";

  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
     " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
     //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
     //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

  if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  {
    echo '<div><center><h1>Prijava uspesno poslata.</h1></center></div>';         
  }else
  {
     echo '<div><center><h1>Greska prilikom slanja prijave. Molimo pokusajte ponovo.</h1></center></div>';
  }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the attachment specific instructions when you don't send one. 
**That means change this:**

```
$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
 "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
 "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
 " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
 "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
 "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
 $message . "\n\n";

$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
 "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
 " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
 //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
 //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
 $data . "\n\n" .
 "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

**To this:**

```
$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
 "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
 "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";

$message = $message; // Leave unchanged
```

But additionally I'd like to point out the fact that you should use an API to send your mails to avoid any kind of unwanted bugs. Moreover it will be easier to develop with it. I recommend PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Here is a quick example on how to use PHPMailer. See how it is simple:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't work without it, because mail() is inside of the if-clausel where it is required to have an attachment. Move the mail() function outside of it and only add the MIME part to the header and message, if there is really an attachment. By the way, you're overwriting $message if you have an attachment.

Like this (isn't tested):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

$to="mares.p@hotmail.com";
$subject="Online Prijava";
$from = stripslashes($_POST['ime'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email_adresa']).">";

if(empty($_POST['ime'])  || empty($_POST['email_adresa']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Greska: nisu uneta sva obavezna polja";
}

$message = "PODACI U PSU:
\n\n Razred: " .$_POST['razred']. "
\n\n Boja: " .$_POST['boja']. "
\n\n Tip dlake: " .$_POST['tip_dlake']. "
\n\n Velicina: " .$_POST['velicina']. "
\n\n Pol: " .$_POST['pol']. "
\n\n Visina: " .$_POST['visina']. "
\n\n Tezina: " .$_POST['tezina']. "
\n\n Ime psa: " .$_POST['ime_psa']. "
\n\n Broj pedigra: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea']. "
\n\n Datum rodjenja: " .$_POST['datum_rodjenja']. "
\n\n Otac: " .$_POST['otac']. "
\n\n Broj pedigrea oca: " .$_POST['broj_pedigrea_oca']. "
\n\n Majka: " .$_POST['majka']. "
\n\n Broj pedigra majke: " .$_POST['broj_pedigra_majke']. "
\n\n Odgajivac: " .$_POST['odgajivac']. "
\n\n
\n\nPODACI O VLASNIKU
\n\n Ime: " .$_POST['ime']. "
\n\n Adresa: " .$_POST['adresa']. "
\n\n Grad: " .$_POST['grad']. "
\n\n Drzava: " .$_POST['drzava']. "
\n\n Telefon: " .$_POST['telefon']. "
\n\n Email adresa: " .$_POST['email_adresa'];

$headers = "From: $from\r\n";

if(!empty($_FILES)) {
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['tmp_name'];
  $type = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['type'];
  $file_name = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['fotokopija_uplatnice']['size'];
if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
  if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){
     $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
     $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
     fclose($file);
     $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
 }

  $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
     "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
     " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  $message .= "\n\n\nThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
     $message . "\n\n";

  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
     " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
     //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
     //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
}
}

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
  {
    echo '<div><center><h1>Prijava uspesno poslata.</h1></center></div>';         
  }else
  {
     echo '<div><center><h1>Greska prilikom slanja prijave. Molimo pokusajte ponovo.</h1></center></div>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. why im not getting message that email is sent?                   2. is there a way to send 2 or 3 attachments at same time

Comment: You're surpressing everything with @. Remove the @ and your if-clausel should receive either true or false.

Comment: still not getting message :S

Comment: It should work, I have it a bit different, but practically the same. You could try to compare it against !== false. mail() will return false if it can't send the mail. One last tip: If you have the chance to use PHPMailer, make use of it. See answer below.